# Three awkward lines of code in just one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element `$el1` which I would like to append to `$el2` by fading in. This is my current code:

```
$el1
    .css('display', 'none')
    .appendTo($el2)
    .fadeIn(300);
```

I find the above terribly awkward. I would much prefer something along the lines of

```
$el1.fadeIn(300, $el2);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it a little...

```
$el2.append($el1.hide().fadeIn(300));
```

Answer (score 5):

1. That's *really* just not terribly awkward code.
2. You can do a teeny bit better:

   ```
   $el1.hide().appendTo($el2).fadeIn(300);
   ```